# emacs projectile: override vcs mode

Tags: emacs, projectile

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 + projectile 0.11.0 (installed using melpa)

When I try to find a file (C-c p f) in an svn project (https) it takes ages before the completion comes up. Additionally I require a secure VPN connection which is not always active.

From the debug stacktrace (see below) I suspect it's due to the svn list (which is also very slow when I run it on command line). 
Projectile is automatically selecting the svn mode because it recognized this project as an svn project however that's not strictly required for me. I'd be fine if projectile would just do a local find (projectile-generic-command)

My questions:

- Does projectile allow me to configure/override the vcs mode somehow (e.g. through .projectile file)?
- I know I can switch to native indexing mode, however I don't want to do that globally. How would I set that up for this project only?
- Any other solutions?

Stacktrace from the debug-on-quit:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  call-process("/bin/bash" nil t nil "-c" "svn list -R . | grep -v '$/' | tr '\\n' '\\0'")
  apply(call-process "/bin/bash" nil t nil ("-c" "svn list -R . | grep -v '$/' | tr '\\n' '\\0'"))
  process-file("/bin/bash" nil t nil "-c" "svn list -R . | grep -v '$/' | tr '\\n' '\\0'")
  shell-command-to-string("svn list -R . | grep -v '$/' | tr '\\n' '\\0'")
  projectile-files-via-ext-command("svn list -R . | grep -v '$/' | tr '\\n' '\\0'")
  projectile-get-repo-files()
  projectile-dir-files-external("<svn_path>" "<svn_path>")
  projectile-dir-files("<svn_path>")
  #[(it) "^H    !\207" [fn it] 2]("<svn_path>")
  mapcar(#[(it) "^H     !\207" [fn it] 2] ("<svn_path>"))
  -mapcat(projectile-dir-files ("<svn_path>"))
  projectile-current-project-files()
  projectile-find-file(nil)
  call-interactively(projectile-find-file nil nil)
```

Comment: I just stumbled upon [configuring projectile's behavior](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#configuring-projectiles-behavior). Somehow I overlooked it initially.
I created a .dir-locals.el with: ```((nil . ((projectile-svn-command . "find . -type f -print0"))))```

I do have a follow up issue as it now where emacs keeps asking me about allowing _The local variables list in ... contains variables that are risky (**)._ ```** projectile-svn-command : "find . -type f -print0"```... (looking into emacs docs)

Comment: Adding ```'(safe-local-variable-values (quote ((projectile-svn-command . "find . -type f -print0")))))``` to my .emacs safe sets the variable